# How to turn off Firefox 3.5's in-browser media player?

Tags: firefox, audio

Firefox 3.5 adds support for OGG and WAV playback using the HTML5 `<audio>` element. Great!

However, it also defaults to opening a media player in the browser whenever I follow a link to OGG or WAV. It's not a plugin, it seems to be implemented as a simple HTML wrapper containing `<audio>`, but I still don't like it. I want to get a prompt to open/download/whatever like with any other media file.

I've set the action for OGG and WAV to ‘Always ask’ in the ‘Applications’ tab on Preferences, but this is ignored. I can't see anything obvious in `about:config`. Except for `media.ogg.enabled`, but that just disables format support so I still get an HTML player for OGG, just one that doesn't work. Gah!

Google's not helping today; do any superusers have a solution, before I go bugging the zilla?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options>Applications in firefox to change you preferences on this.

Comment: I have done (mentioned in question). They're set to ‘Always ask’, but Firefox still uses the inline player instead of ever asking.

Comment: My appologies, I sould have read more closely.  If you go to tools>add-ons>plug-ins and disable quicktime, you will have to select what you want firefox to do.

Comment: I do not have QuickTime or any other media player plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it doesn't seem to be possible currently. Discussion in [bug 498523](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=498523).